# Update Mysql database using data inserted into Jtable

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to be able to update my MySQL database through user insertion in a JTable where I display my database, but based off my code right now I get a error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 )

This error occurs when I click my button to update the database.

This is my main class:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

This is my class for my main menu:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{

    JLabel label;
    JMenu Add;
    JMenu remove;
    JMenu items;
    JMenu vendors;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenuItem addCustomer;
    JMenuItem addVendors;
    JMenuItem addProducts;
    JMenuItem removeCustomer;
    JMenuItem removeProduct;
    JMenuItem removeVendor;

    MyFrame(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Inventory Software");
        label.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 30));

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        Add = new JMenu("Add");
        remove = new JMenu("Edit");
        items = new JMenu("Items");
        vendors = new JMenu("Vendors");

        addCustomer = new JMenuItem("Add Customers");
        addVendors = new JMenuItem("Add Vendors");
        addProducts = new JMenuItem("Add Products");

        removeCustomer = new JMenuItem("Edit Customer");
        removeProduct = new JMenuItem("Edit Product");
        removeVendor = new JMenuItem("Edit Vendor");

        remove.add(removeCustomer);
        remove.add(removeProduct);
        remove.add(removeVendor);

        Add.add(addCustomer);
        Add.add(addProducts);
        Add.add(addVendors);

        menuBar.add(Add);
        menuBar.add(remove);
        menuBar.add(items);
        menuBar.add(vendors);

        addCustomer.addActionListener(new WindowAC());
        addVendors.addActionListener(new WindowAV());
        addProducts.addActionListener(new WindowAP());
        removeCustomer.addActionListener(new WindowRC());
        removeVendor.addActionListener(new WindowRV());
        removeProduct.addActionListener(new WindowRP());

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 300));
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        this.add(label);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setTitle("Intact Communications Inventory Software");
    }
}
```

This is my code to edit my customers in my JTable and update them in my database:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;

public class WindowRC implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("Edit Customer".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            JFrame windowRC = new JFrame();
            JTable table = new JTable();
            JButton button = new JButton("Update Database");

            table.setBounds(268, 52, 283, 198);
            button.setBounds(350, 180, 100, 60);
            button.setFocusable(false);

            windowRC.add(button);
            windowRC.add(new JScrollPane(table));

            windowRC.setSize(750, 750);
            windowRC.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            windowRC.setTitle("Remove Product Data");
            windowRC.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            windowRC.setVisible(true);
            windowRC.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/inventoryapp", "root", "P@kist@n1");
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                String query = "SELECT * from addcustomer";
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

                int cols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                String[] colName = new String[cols];
                for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
                    colName[i] = rsmd.getColumnName(i + 1);
                model.setColumnIdentifiers(colName);

                String name, address, email, tel, fax;

                while (rs.next()) {
                    name = rs.getString(1);
                    address = rs.getString(2);
                    email = rs.getString(3);
                    tel = rs.getString(4);
                    fax = rs.getString(5);

                    String[] row = {name, address, email, tel, fax};
                    model.addRow(row);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException classNotFoundException) {
                classNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
            }

            if ("Update Database".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
                System.out.println("Update happening!!!");
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    private Object Component;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1) {
                        try {
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/inventoryapp", "root", "P@kist@n1");
                            Statement st = con.createStatement();
                            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                            int row = table.getSelectedRow();

                            for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                                String name = (model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
                                String address = model.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
                                String email = model.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
                                String tel = model.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
                                String fax = model.getValueAt(i, 4).toString();

                                PreparedStatement updateQuery = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE addcustomer" + "SET Name = ?" + "WHERE Name = ? "+ row);

                                updateQuery.setString(0,name);
                                updateQuery.setString(1,address);
                                updateQuery.setString(2,email);
                                updateQuery.setString(3,tel);
                                updateQuery.setString(4,fax);

                                updateQuery.executeUpdate();

                                st.close();
                                con.close();

                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((java.awt.Component) Component, "Data Edited");
                            }
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException classNotFoundException) {
                            classNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

I tried multiple different UPDATE statements, but each time I would get an error or it won't update my database that I connected to.

Comment: *I get a error: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 )* - so this has nothing to do with the JTable. This is an SQL problem. The way to solve an SQL problem is to first test the SQL statement by hardcoding the data. Once this works, then you attempt to provide dynamic data from the JTable. I would start by looking at your SQ:L statement: 1) why do you have the "row" variable as part of the SQL? The point of using a PreparedStatment is that all the variable data is passed by parameters. 2) Why do you only have 2 "?" but attempt to set 5 parameters for the statement.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I removed the "row" variable, and also fixed my mistake of only having 2 "?" I now have one for each of my parameters but I still am getting the error.                                                                                                                                      This is my current sql statement now:                                                                                PreparedStatement updateQuery = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE addcustomer" + "SET Name = ?, SET Address = ?, SET Email = ?, SET Tel = ?, SET FAX = ? ");